# How to convert sequence of ASCII code into string in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, string, ascii

I have an sequence of ASCII codes in string format like (7297112112121326610511411610410097121). How to convert this into text format.

I tried below code :

```
func convertAscii(asciiStr: String) {
    var asciiString = ""
    for asciiChar in asciiStr {
        if let number = UInt8(asciiChar, radix: 2) { // Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UInt8' with an argument list of type '(Character, radix: Int)'
            print(number)
            let character = String(describing: UnicodeScalar(number))
            asciiString.append(character)
        }
    }
}

convertAscii(asciiStr: "7297112112121326610511411610410097121")
```

But getting error in `if let number` line.

Comment: 1. it's not a binary number, therefore you cannot use `radix` with value `2`. 2. do you know the size of each character? Does every character take 2 or 3 letters? ASCII values are either 0-127 or 0-255.

Comment: “Happy Birthday" – but the format is highly ambiguous (mixing 2 and 3 digit numbers): The program would have to guess if 112112 means 112,112 or 11,21,12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned decimal ASCII values are in range of 0-255 and can be more than 2 digits

Based on Sulthan's answer and assuming there are no characters < 32 (0x20) and > 199 (0xc7) in the text this approach checks the first character of the cropped string. If it's "1" the character is represented by 3 digits otherwise 2.

```
func convertAscii(asciiStr: String) {
    var source = asciiStr

    var result = ""

    while source.count >= 2 {
        let digitsPerCharacter = source.hasPrefix("1") ? 3 : 2
        let charBytes = source.prefix(digitsPerCharacter)
        source = String(source.dropFirst(digitsPerCharacter))
        let number = Int(charBytes)!
        let character = UnicodeScalar(number)!
        result += String(character)
    }

    print(result) // "Happy Birthday"
}

convertAscii(asciiStr: "7297112112121326610511411610410097121")
```

Comment: Much easier to make result a string and append the character

Comment: `var result = ""` 
        `result.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(number)!))`

Comment: Another option is to make result an array of UnicodeScalar and then create a view from it `var result: [UnicodeScalar] = []` and `String(String.UnicodeScalarView(result))`

Comment: You can also treat it just as Data creating a Data object, append each byte  and then convert it to String. `var data = Data()` `let byte = UInt8(charBytes, radix: 10)!` 
`data.append(byte)`  `let string = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)!`

Comment: @vadian - Thanks for your quick response. And it is working fine.

Comment: @Sabs `var source = asciiStr` 
    `var data = Data()` 
    `while source.count >= 2 {` 
        `let digitsPerCharacter = source.hasPrefix("1") ? 3 : 2` 
        `data.append(UInt8(source.prefix(digitsPerCharacter))!)` 
        `source.removeFirst(digitsPerCharacter)` 
   `}` 
    `let string = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)!`

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the string to be composed of characters where every character is represented by 2 decimal letters, then something like this would work (this is just an example, not optimal).

```
func convertAscii(asciiStr: String) {
    var source = asciiStr

    var characters: [String] = []

    let digitsPerCharacter = 2

    while source.count >= digitsPerCharacter {
        let charBytes = source.prefix(digitsPerCharacter)
        source = String(source.dropFirst(digitsPerCharacter))
        let number = Int(charBytes, radix: 10)!
        let character = UnicodeScalar(number)!
        characters.append(String(character))
    }

    let result: String = characters.joined()
    print(result)
}

convertAscii(asciiStr: "7297112112121326610511411610410097121")
```

However, the format itself is ambigious because ASCII characters can take from 1 to 3 decimal digits, therefore to parse correctly, you need all characters to have the same length (e.g. `1` should be `001`).

Note that I am taking always the same number of letters, then convert them to a number and then create a character the number.